# pandas: how to eliminate rows with value ending with a specific character?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame as follows:

```
mail = DataFrame({'mail' : ['adv@gmail.com', 'fhngn@gmail.com', 'foinfo@yahoo.com', 'njfjrnfjrn@yahoo.com', 'nfjebfjen@hotmail.com', 'gnrgiprou@hotmail.com', 'jfei@hotmail.com']})
```

that looks like:

```
                    mail
0          adv@gmail.com
1        fhngn@gmail.com
2       foinfo@yahoo.com
3   njfjrnfjrn@yahoo.com
4  nfjebfjen@hotmail.com
5  gnrgiprou@hotmail.com
6       jfei@hotmail.com
```

What I want to do is to filter out (elimiante) all those rows in which the value in the column mail ends with '@gmail.com'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) and negate the result of the boolean Series with `~`:

```
mail[~mail['mail'].str.endswith('@gmail.com')]
```

Which produces:

```
                    mail
2       foinfo@yahoo.com
3   njfjrnfjrn@yahoo.com
4  nfjebfjen@hotmail.com
5  gnrgiprou@hotmail.com
6       jfei@hotmail.com
```

Pandas has many other [vectorised string operations](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) which are accessible through the `.str` accessor. Many of these are instantly familiar from Python's own string methods, but come will built in handling of `NaN` values.

Answer (score 2):

A column with type `str` has [a field `.str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#working-with-text-data) on it, using which you can access the standard functions defined for a single `str`:

```
[6]: mail['mail'].str.endswith('gmail.com')
      Out[6]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
Name: mail, dtype: bool
```

Then you can filter using this Series:

```
[7]: mail[~mail['mail'].str.endswith('gmail.com')]
      Out[7]:
                    mail
2       foinfo@yahoo.com
3   njfjrnfjrn@yahoo.com
4  nfjebfjen@hotmail.com
5  gnrgiprou@hotmail.com
6       jfei@hotmail.com
```

A [similar property `.dt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.html#pandas.Series.dt) exists for accessing date/time related properties of a column if it contains date-data.